# how to access MATLAB GUI functions from a separate m file - matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

i have a function called main(). in this 'main' i call another function A().
i have a GUIde and have a variable 'number' in this.
how can i access 'number' from A() or change the value of 'number' from A()?

1- the code below doesn't work.

```
main(handles)
  %some code
  A(handles);

  function A(handles)
    set(handles.number,0);
  end
end
```

2- and this one doesn't work too.

```
main(handles)
  %some code
  A(handles);

  function A(handles)
    handles.setNumberFnc(5);
  end
end


%%%%%in GUI i have this function.

function setNumberFnc(n)
  handles.number = n;
  guidata(hObject, handles);
```

i know this function has no 'hObject' i don't know what to do?

3- can i use 'Global number' in GUI and in A()?

Comment: I suggest you to use the debugger - go step by step, and watch values of `handles` and `hObject`...

Comment: Can you show us the line that defines your variable `handles`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem.
Only it was necessary to define global the variable 'number' in all the necessary functions. now easily i can change the value of 'number' in GUI or in A() function.
no need to 'set' function.

```
main()
  %some code
  A();

  function A()
    global number;
    disp(number);
    number = 5;
  end
end
```

and in GUIde:

```
function B_Callback(hObject, ~, handles)
global number;
number = 2;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are solving the problem the other way around that I usually do it. For me, the GUI is the main object, and I define my button callbacks and such to call external scripts and functions.

You want to run a seperate script or function which then modifies the GUI. This is fine too! All you need is the handle of the GUI, which you can get, for example, with `gcf` (assuming the GUI is the currently active figure window). However, your `setNumberFcn` is a [local function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) (or possibly a [nested function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html), which is almost the same thing), and you cannot call it from a different script or function file. Instead, you would have to put it into your `main.m` file, in the manner of

```
function main()

  fig_handle = gcf;
  numfield_handle = findobj(gcf, 'NumFieldTagThatYouDefinedInGUIDE');

  function setNumberFcn(numfield_handle, number)
      set(numfield_handle, 'String', num2str(number))
  end

end
```